# .htaccess url rewrite multiple directories to GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok so I have a site that I want to write rewrite rules for. I don't have much experience with rewrites.

My .htaccess is in /foo/, not the root. Here's what I want

```
Case 1: example.com/foo/bar/ --> example.com/foo/includes/page.php?school=bar&id=

Case 2: example.com/foo/bar/1 --> example.com/foo/includes/page.php?school=bar&id=1
```

Here is what I have

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^(bar|baz)/(.*)$    ./includes/pages.php?school=$1&id=$2    [NC,L]
```

There are only two possible values for school `bar` and `baz`. The `id` can have any number of values.
The above code works in Case 2 but doesn't work in case 1. It seems to externally redirect in case 1 to different urls depending on if there is a trailing slash or not. No idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (in `foo` folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/

RewriteRule ^(bar|baz)/([0-9]*)$ includes/page.php?school=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Nope, this breaks both the cases. The case 2 which was working before gives 404 with this

Comment: Ok after I realized the changes to my htaccess were somehow being cached by the browser I used the incongnito mode and it seems to work for `/foo/bar/` but not for `/foo/bar`. Any solution to that? Other than that trailing slash it all seems good. So thanks!

Comment: Ok I fixed the trailing slash problem too by using `^(bar|baz)/?(.*)$`